# Cross-thread operation not valid: problem

Tags: vb.net

I am working in Visual Studio 2019 and writing in Visual Basic. I get this error: Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'lblTesting' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.' (lblTesting is just a label for testing purposes).

I call the FrmContacts like this:

```vb
Private Sub ContactsToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ContactsToolStripMenuItem.Click
    Me.Enabled = False
    FrmContacts.Show()
End Sub
```

and return from the form like this:

```vb
Private Sub FrmContacts_Closed(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Closed
    Me.Close()
    FrmMain.Enabled = True
End Sub
```

The error pops up when I exit FrmContacts.

I tried deleting the form and recreating it but the error is there as soon as I add any control. I am dumbfounded. Searching has not revealed any hints.

Comment: None of that code refers to `lblTesting` or does anything on a background thread so may try showing us the relevant code.

Comment: I have no code relating to lblTesting. I just placed it on the form and exited. It will exit fine with no controls on the form.

Comment: You must be doing something that uses a secondary thread, e.g. the `BackgroundWorker.DoWork` event or the `Timer.Elapsed` event. You must have some code that refers to `lblTesting`.

Comment: Maybe look at the exception and its stack trace, which tells you where the exception was thrown. That information is provided for a reason so look at it.

Comment: I've never looked at anything like that. I am new at programming so will look and see. Other times I created forms and called them all worked okay. I will poke around.

Comment: I don't know what changed. If I take the close statement out, all is fine. On forms I did before today, I used the close statement. Those forms still work fine. Beats me what is different now. Thanks for trying to help me.

Comment: Ah, I didn't notice that. How does it make sense to be calling `Close` in the event handler that's executed when the form has closed? You can't close something twice. Also, these days, you ought to be handling `FormClosing` and `FormClosed` rather than `Closing` and `Closed`.

Comment: Solved: On my other forms I was using a Button to exit the form and the Me.Close worked. On these forms I was putting the Me.Close in the close routine. My bad. Lesson learned!

Answer (score 0):

I had to take out the Me.Close() because I was closing a closed form. The new code works fine. It is:

```
Private Sub FrmContacts_Closed(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Closed
    FrmMain.Enabled = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, if your intention is to make the "main" form inaccessible until the "child" form is closed, then simply use [ShowDialog()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.showdialog?view=netcore-3.1) instead:

> You can use this method to display a modal dialog box in your
>   application. When this method is called, the code following it is not
>   executed until after the dialog box is closed.

```
Private Sub ContactsToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ContactsToolStripMenuItem.Click
    FrmContacts.ShowDialog()
End Sub
```